# Using jstree "offline" with IE11

Tags: angularjs, security, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, jstree

I'm using [jstree](https://www.jstree.com/) v3.2.1 wrapped with [ngJsTree](https://github.com/ezraroi/ngJsTree) in an AngularJS web-app to be used **mainly** on IE11 browsers.

I found that users who could not connect to the internet, due to their company policies, could not load properly the jstree I use within my forementioned web-app, on the other hand users who do access to the internet see everything just fine.

In particular the former users see just the spinner of jstree loading **frozen** and the "Loading..." text, which is strange because I set up the jstree config object to translate it into another string.

Moreover, I put a breakpoint inside the callback function associated to the ready event, and it never gets called.

Finally, the jstree part of my web-app works uber fine with both online and offline users when they reach it through Chrome or Firefox.

Is there any restriction on the online/offline usage of this library when in combo with some sort of IE11 strict security policy?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem with IE11 in an environment without online access and custom security policies.
In our case the security policies somehow influenced the compatibility mode of IE which caused the problem.
After setting the compatibility mode manually in the Page header as described below everything works:
(After the Deployment we also needed to close and reopen the Browser, simply pressing refresh didn't change the compatibilty mode)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10; IE=9; IE=8;" />
```